# Is there a way to display the users who have shared a post with Facebook Graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, share, facebook-opengraph

According to the graph it looks like only likes and comments can be seen. There is no way of finding out list of users who shared a post?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see getting who shared a post documented in the API. I could find no shares connection under the post object in the graph, nor does there appear to be a FQL shares table available.  However, I found a link to get a UI view of the shares:  https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id={post_id}

e.g. https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=10150560402022959

You might be able to scrape this URL for the information you're after.